# How to pass a char *** from C# to native function in DLL

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

In a C++ dynamic library there is an export method defined as shown below

```
int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall TCPGetConnectionNames(char *** ConnectionNames)
```

I am looking for an answer on what input parameter in C# I would use for the char *** ConectionNames?
For a char* parameter I use c# string type.
But what would I use for char *** in c#?

```
static extern int  TCPGetConnectionNames(?????? ConnectionNames);
```

Googles for solution but found none

Comment: ref Int[] would be int** , and  string would be char *. So for char*** in c# would the representation be ref string[]?

Comment: char** would be somewhat sensible, char*** is not.  The caller has no idea how large the arrays might be.  Post tested C++ code that demonstrates usage.

Comment: If you are passing back a pointer to an array, how is that pointer supposed to be freed?

Comment: @HansPassant Not uncommon to just read up until a null pointer. I agree more information is needed.

Comment: You have an array of string pointers.  The array is terminated with a null (zero) after last pointers.  Each string is terminated with a '\0'.  The input parameter would be a IntPtr.  then you would have to enumerate through pointers until you got a null.  why are you using __stdcall instead of c language?  If you want stdcall make sure in c# you are also using stdcall.  c# will default to c language.

Comment: @jdweng Default for `DllImport` is `StdCall` anyway

Comment: Hans Passant I did not write the C++ DLL. I just have the DLL file and what the export method signatures are, and I am using the C++ DLL in a C# application.

Comment: Charlieface I did not write the C++ DLL. I just have the DLL file and what the export method signatures are, and I am using the C++ DLL in a C# application.

Comment: jdwenf ; I did not write the C++ DLL. I just have the DLL file and what the export method signatures are, and I am using the C++ DLL in a C# application.

Answer (score -2):

Without further info on how this function is meant to be used, it's hard to say. but at a guess:

- The variable is a pointer to a pointer to an array of string pointers.
- The array appears to be null-terminated, as do the strings.
- So you can use `out` to dereference the first level of pointers.
- Then loop that pointer reading in `IntPtr` sized values, which are themselves string pointers. Stop when you get a null pointer.
- Null-terminated ANSI strings can be read using `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.
- You need to free that memory somehow. Presumably the library has a `Free` method, call it in a `finally`.
- The return value is unclear. It may be an error number, or an error `bool`. If the latter, you can use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`

```cs
static extern int TCPGetConnectionNames([Out] out IntPtr ConnectionNames);
```

You can use it like this

```cs
var list = new List<string>();

if (!TCPGetConnectionNames(out var ptr)
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

try
{    
    for (var offset = ptr; ; offset += IntPtr.Size)
    {
        var str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(offset))
        if (str == null)
            break;
        list.Add(str);
    }
}
finally
{
    FreePointerUsingSomeFunction(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I would test if Marshal.ReadIntPtr(offset) == 0 before converting to string.

Comment: @jdweng You get a `null` in that case, which is what I test for on the next line.

Comment: What happens when you try to convert a null pointer to a string?

Comment: I just said: you get a `null` string, and I'm testing that.

Comment: The char *** ConnectionName  it states is "an  Array to fill in". I am guessing it is an array of strings

Comment: Thank for suggestion. I will try the [Out] out IntPtr ConnectionNames) suggestion. There are a number of other exported methods and some of them do free memory.  My job is to get a c# application to be able to call the export methods in the c++ DLL. Most of all the other export methods input parameter are self-explanatory.

Comment: Charlieface that is some fancy code you posted. Do you know of any links or videos that I could view to learn more in this IntPtr information? Thank you for your insight.